# How to use groupby on multiple indexes and then use count aggregate function and then use one of the multiple indexes to get the sum of count?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have created a dataframe in python lets say:

```
testingdf = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,1,2,1,2],
                          'B':[1,2,1,2,3,3],
                          'C':[9,8,7,6,5,6]})
```

Now i want to get count of column 'C' according to 'A' and 'B' for that i am performing

```
testingdf.groupby(['A','B']).count()
```

to get:

```
        C
A   B   
1   1   2
    3   1
2   2   2
    3   1
```

Now i want to get the Sum value of this count of 'C' with Respect to 'A' like:

```
A   C
1   3
2   3
```

After grouping 'A' and 'B' i can select the 'A' column and apply the sum aggregate function on it. So I wanted to know what is the efficient way of doing this.

Note** : This sum is just an example i want to perform different things too like aggregate function to get max and min of count of C with respect to A after grouping A and B together.

P.S. : Sorry I should have had mentioned this earlier, but I don't want to use groupby twice. I want to know the most efficient way to get the results. Even if that means I don't have to use groupby.

Comment: Try `.reset_index()`? i.e. `testingdf.groupby(['A','B']).count().reset_index().groupby("A").sum()`. But in this case, isn't that the same as just `testingdf.groupby("A").count()`? i.e. the sum of counts is the same as the counts of the final grouping var.

Comment: I think your sample data doesn't exactly match to the rest of your stuff

Comment: Sorry i just now realised that. I have modified the sample data

Answer (score 1):

you can use `sum()` method with `level` parameter after `groupby()`+`count()`:

```
out=testingdf.groupby(['A','B']).count().sum(level=0).reset_index()
```

OR

other way is groupby twice:

```
out=testingdf.groupby(['A','B']).count().groupby(level=0).sum().reset_index()
```

output for your given data:

```
    A   C
0   1   2
1   2   2
2   3   1
```

Comment: Sorry I should have had mentioned this earlier, but I don't want to use groupby twice. I want to know the most efficient way to get the results. Even if that means I don't have to use groupby

Comment: @Manku Sir then use the first one it is more efficeient

Comment: Actually that method internally uses groupby and is depreciated and is going to get removed in future releases.

Comment: @Manku who said this?

Comment: I had tried this earlier and it showed me the warning message that using levels in aggregate functions is depreciated and is going to get removed in the future releases.

Comment: @Manku what is your pandas version?I didn't get any warning like this!

Comment: I am using pandas 1.3.1

Comment: @Manku ohh I am using `1.2.4` anyway but since it's a warning so you can ignore it...btw I don't think that there is more efficient ways other than these 2

Comment: Yes but still using level inside aggreagate functions uses groupby internally so both basically do the same thing so the method 2 is better that way. Also thank you for your help. I will try to look some other alternatives than groupby for now then like pivot_table.

Comment: @Manku btw if your query is solved then you can try considering accepting the answer to indicate others that the issue is solved(click on tick to make it green)

Comment: Actually I still want to know more optimal solution to my query.

Comment: @Manku alright then wait for 2-3 days or even a week if anyone doesn't answer any more efficient solution then accept it...btw I would also want to know if there is more efficient solution than this